Uploading images to IPFS... Initialization failed
Good afternoon.
Please tell me what the problem is, I run the yarn start command and it doesn’t upload files to Pinata, although my plan there allows it to be done there is an error and the code is below: saved because:
app.ts
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

import { toNano } from "ton-core";
import { readdir } from "fs/promises";

import { openWallet } from "./utils";
import { waitSeqno } from "./delay";
import { NftCollection } from "./contracts/NftCollection";
import { NftItem } from "./contracts/NftItem";
import { updateMetadataFiles, uploadFolderToIPFS } from "./metadata";
import { GetGemsSaleData, NftSale } from "./contracts/NftSale";
import { NftMarketplace } from "./contracts/NftMarketplace";

dotenv.config();

async function init() {
  try {
    const metadataFolderPath = "./data/metadata/";
    const imagesFolderPath = "./data/images/";

    const wallet = await openWallet(process.env.MNEMONIC!.split(" "), true);

  console.log("Started uploading images to IPFS...");
  const imagesIpfsHash = await uploadFolderToIPFS(imagesFolderPath);
  console.log(
    `Successfully uploaded the pictures to ipfs: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${imagesIpfsHash}`
  );

  console.log("Started uploading metadata files to IPFS...");
  await updateMetadataFiles(metadataFolderPath, imagesIpfsHash);
  const metadataIpfsHash = await uploadFolderToIPFS(metadataFolderPath);
  console.log(
    `Successfully uploaded the metadata to ipfs: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${metadataIpfsHash}`
  );

  console.log("Start deploy of nft collection...");
  const collectionData = {
    ownerAddress: wallet.contract.address,
    royaltyPercent: 0.05, // 0.05 = 5%
    royaltyAddress: wallet.contract.address,
    nextItemIndex: 0,
    collectionContentUrl: `ipfs://${metadataIpfsHash}/collection.json`,
    commonContentUrl: `ipfs://${metadataIpfsHash}/`,
  };
  const collection = new NftCollection(collectionData);
  let seqno = await collection.deploy(wallet);
  console.log(`Collection deployed: ${collection.address}`);
  await waitSeqno(seqno, wallet);

  // Deploy nft items
  const files = await readdir(metadataFolderPath);
  files.pop();
  let index = 0;

  seqno = await collection.topUpBalance(wallet, files.length);
  await waitSeqno(seqno, wallet);
  console.log(`Balance top-upped`);

  for (const file of files) {
    try {
      console.log(`Start deploy of ${index + 1} NFT`);
    const mintParams = {
      queryId: 0,
      itemOwnerAddress: wallet.contract.address,
      itemIndex: index,
      amount: toNano("0.05"),
      commonContentUrl: file,
    };
    const nftItem = new NftItem(collection);
    seqno = await nftItem.deploy(wallet, mintParams);
    console.log(`Successfully deployed ${index + 1} NFT`);
    await waitSeqno(seqno, wallet);
    index++;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error deploying ${index + 1} NFT:`, error);
  }
}

  console.log("Start deploy of new marketplace  ");
  const marketplace = new NftMarketplace(wallet.contract.address);
  seqno = await marketplace.deploy(wallet);
  await waitSeqno(seqno, wallet);
  console.log("Successfully deployed new marketplace");

  try {
    const nftToSaleAddress = await NftItem.getAddressByIndex(collection.address, 0);
  const saleData: GetGemsSaleData = {
    isComplete: false,
    createdAt: Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000),
    marketplaceAddress: marketplace.address,
    nftAddress: nftToSaleAddress,
    nftOwnerAddress: null,
    fullPrice: toNano("10"),
    marketplaceFeeAddress: wallet.contract.address,
    marketplaceFee: toNano("1"),
    royaltyAddress: wallet.contract.address,
    royaltyAmount: toNano("0.5"),
  };
  const nftSaleContract = new NftSale(saleData);
  seqno = await nftSaleContract.deploy(wallet);
  await waitSeqno(seqno, wallet);

} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error setting up NFT for sale:', error);
}
} catch (error) {
console.error('Initialization failed:', error);
}
}

void init();


my mistake:
% yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ tsc --skipLibCheck && node dist/app.js
Started uploading images to IPFS...
Initialization failed: {
reason: 'FORBIDDEN',
details: 'Account blocked due to plan usage limit'
}
✨  Done in 3.96s.

Account blocked due to plan usage limit

This might be the fix -> whenever we create an api key, we should give 500 max uses or else it will show the above error during post request.enter image description here
